# Seeking open source alternative of Las Tools

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, lidar, las, lastools

I am finding **any open source alternative of Las tools** , i Google but i found las Utitly which is also not the Open source alternative But i want open source alternative of Las Tools,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on needed functionality. Some combination of [pdal](https://www.pdal.io/) and [cgal](http://www.cgal.org/) may suits you.

Comment: Fusion (http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion.html)The visualization system consists of two main programs, FUSION and LDV , implemented as Microsoft Windows applications coded in C++ using the Microsoft Foundation Classes. The primary interface, provided by FUSION, consists of a graphics display window and a control window. The FUSION display presents all project data using a 2D display typical of geographic information systems. It supports a variety of data types and formats but requires that all data be geo-referenced using the same projection system and units of measurement.